# Split a wav file into regions based on other regions/files

Tags: regions, batch-processing, dialogue, software, cutting

someone on my team split a giant wav file into smaller regions, but it accidentally got normalized on a file by file level. Is there a way to compare the small files/regions (which are numerically ordered) to the large wav file and have it simply slice it up in all the same places, presuming there's no added time or lost time (that the regions were only cut/split, no added or lost time) and give me new files of the same time length?

It's sort of like I have the original puzzle image, but need to re-cut it up into pieces. They have the pieces, but the puzzle image is blurry.

Note: I am using Logic 9. I also have DP7

Answer (score 1):

as long as the files are lined up exactly into the same time position as the rendered file, you could easily use a quickkeys script to do this.

just group the tracks, tab, b, repeat.

IMO quickkeys is an invaluable addition to any daw for the macro looping capabilities.

Comment: If I were using Pro Tools, that might work (?), but sadly, I'm using Logic Pro. I also have Digital Performer, maybe there's an option within that program, though I do not know it as well.

Comment: there has to be a way to execute the same type of thing in logic or DP via the keyboard.  its just a matter of splitting the rendered files at the region boundaries of the original files.  quickkeys will execute whatever key command works in the program of your choice on a loop.  the solution's got to be in there somewhere.